# Transforming an R Shiny Web Application into a Mobile App

Tags: javascript, r, angularjs, shiny, web-applications

I've recently built a fully functional web app which I was able to get up and running on a cloud server, and then successfully embed onto my company's website. However, when viewing the application on a mobile device, the user interface looks poorly designed in contrast with the desktop version, and some of the functionality is lost.

My guess is that these limitations on the mobile side stem from the fact that I've embedded the web-app as a single HTML object/widget. I've read some literature and blog-posts about using flutter and shinyMobile to transform the web app into a mobile version, however at this point that's not a feasible remedy for me (due to lack of knowledge in that area and lack of time I can devote to learning it). I've also been using the devtools to look at how the app behaves when the user engages with it, however I'm not well-versed on how a 'web manifest' works.

Hence I was wondering if anybody had suggestions on how I can configure the appearance of the shiny app on a mobile device? Ideally a solution that does not involve extensive knowledge of JS or languages other than R and HTML/CSS.

Please let me know if you need any clarification or additional information.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

html and css are enough to improve the way your shiny app is presented on mobile devices. Shiny uses bootstrap for the styling by default and you have several ways to work with the updated versions of this css framework.
If the app is used by people from many parts of the world, I recommend that you load bootstrap from their cdn. In your app.R :

```
tags$head(
  tags$link(href = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", rel="stylesheet", integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor", crossorigin="anonymous")
)
```

Otherwise you can add it to the project by creating a folder in the project root directory with the name www and then download bootstrap.

```
tags$head(
  tags$link(href = "bootstrap.min.css", rel = "stylesheet")
)
```

For reference,  [this app](https://auth.cleanknightsrd.com/) is completely created with shiny and only uses bootstrap if you want to take a look, it is really mobile friendly. I hope I've helped